# I can't put a default schema in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

The text field "Default Schema" is disabled, I don't know why!

[image]

I try to run this:

```
use DB;

ALTER USER [user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [schema];
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USER'.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but the problem is that `alter user` syntax was introduced in SQL 2008 as was `create schema`, which explains why it's telling you that the syntax is not valid. I was a baby DBA in the 2005 era, but something in my memory tells me that there was a conflation of users and schemas around that time that got separated in SQL 2008.

Comment: Even the "Extended Support" for SQL Server 2005 ended [three years ago](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2005) - it's **highest time** to upgrade!!

Comment: Can it be that a database in a **SQL Server 2000** compatibility mode?